# Using IS NULL in CASE Expression in WHERE Clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, null, case

I have a `WHERE` clause that I want to use a `CASE` expression in. However, my `CASE` expression needs to check if a field `IS NULL`.

If the `@UserRole` variable value = 'Analyst', then the `SupervisorApprovedBy` column value must be `NULL`. Otherwise, I am saying return all data i.e. `SupervisorApprovedBy = SupervisorApprovedBy`.

What do I need to change to the below?

```
WHERE SupervisorApprovedBy = 
CASE 
    WHEN @UserRole = 'Analyst' THEN NULL
    ELSE SupervisorApprovedBy
END
```

I cannot use `=` for `NULL`. Tested and does not work.

I would want all rows returned including those where `SupervisorApprovedBy IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: Please, could you add some sample data and the desired result?

Comment: Could someone please explain why this is on hold and why so many down votes? It's really a simple question as to how can I use CASE in a WHERE clause to check if a field IS NULL. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are making it harder than it should be.

If @UserRole is 'Analyst' then also SupervisorApprovedBy should be null? Else return everything?

```
WHERE (@UserRole = 'Analyst' AND SupervisorApprovedBy IS NULL ) 
OR (ISNULL(@UserRole, '') <> 'Analyst')
```

Comment: This is the best answer. Lots of us are thinking linearly in logic which makes simple logic convoluted and thus struggle to get it to work.

Answer (score 13):

The problem is likely the comparison to `NULL`, as explained in [David Spillett's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/182331/using-is-null-in-case-statement-in-where-clause/182334#182334) above. When `@UserRole = 'Analyst'`, the comparison `SupervisorApprovedBy = NULL` will give `UNKNOWN` (and the row won't pass the `WHERE` test).

You can rewrite with nested `CASE` expressions:

```
WHERE 1 =
  CASE 
    WHEN @UserRole = 'Analyst' THEN 
        CASE WHEN SupervisorApprovedBy IS NULL THEN 1 END
    WHEN SupervisorApprovedBy IS NOT NULL THEN 1
  END
```

Or a complicated `CASE` expression:

```
WHERE 1 =
  CASE 
    WHEN @UserRole = 'Analyst' AND SupervisorApprovedBy IS NULL THEN 1
    WHEN @UserRole = 'Analyst' THEN 0
    WHEN SupervisorApprovedBy IS NOT NULL THEN 1
  END
```

or with a bit more easy to understand `AND` / `OR`:

```
WHERE 
    @UserRole = 'Analyst'  AND SupervisorApprovedBy IS NULL 
 OR @UserRole <> 'Analyst' AND SupervisorApprovedBy IS NOT NULL 
 OR @UserRole IS NULL      AND SupervisorApprovedBy IS NOT NULL
```

---

Another issue is that `SupervisorApprovedBy = SupervisorApprovedBy` (and the equivalent `SupervisorApprovedBy IS NOT NULL` I used above) will not give you "all data". The rows where `SupervisorApprovedBy` is null will not be returned. If you do want them all, the conditions should be all adjusted:

```
WHERE 1 =
  CASE 
    WHEN @UserRole = 'Analyst' THEN 
        CASE WHEN SupervisorApprovedBy IS NULL THEN 1 END
    ELSE 1
  END


WHERE 1 =
  CASE 
    WHEN @UserRole = 'Analyst' AND SupervisorApprovedBy IS NULL THEN 1
    WHEN @UserRole = 'Analyst' THEN 0
    ELSE 1
  END


WHERE 
    @UserRole = 'Analyst'  AND SupervisorApprovedBy IS NULL 
 OR @UserRole <> 'Analyst' 
 OR @UserRole IS NULL
```

Comment: [Discussion moved to chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63155/discussion-between-daniel-bjork-and-ypercube)

Answer (score 3):

Simply `WHEN <FieldOrVariable> IS NULL THEN <output>`.

Or for the inverse: `WHEN <FieldOrVariable> IS NOT NULL THEN <output>`.

<sup><sup>("WHEN NOT FieldOrVariable IS NULL THEN " would also work but the above reads better so is less likely to be misunderstood later)</sup></sup>

The same is true for other conditional clauses like those relating to `IF` and `ON`.

You can check if a field or variable is equal to NULL because all comparisons to NULL return NULL (which in a `CASE` or `IF` predicate is taken as meaning false), so `WHEN <FieldOrVariable> = NULL THEN <output>` and `WHEN <FieldOrVariable> <> NULL THEN <output>` will never match. `NULL` is essentially "unknown" so if you ask `IF @value = NULL` you are asking "is @value equal to something unknown" to which the only answer is "don't know". Even `IF NULL = NULL PRINT 'NULL is NULL'` will not work because it is asking "is something unknown equal to something else unknown", which is why we have the extra syntax `IS NULL` for dealing with circumstances where we need to know if a value is currently unknown.

Comment: That doesn't really fit into my code above

Answer (score 3):

How about this. Obviously replace 'X' with whatever value wouldn't ever exist.

```
WHERE ISNULL(SupervisorApprovedBy,'X') = 
CASE 
    WHEN @UserRole = 'Analyst' THEN 'X'
    ELSE SupervisorApprovedBy
END
```

If you want it to return NULL's all the time.

```
WHERE ISNULL(SupervisorApprovedBy,'X') IN ( 
CASE 
    WHEN @UserRole = 'Analyst' THEN 'X'
    ELSE SupervisorApprovedBy
END, 'X')
```

Or as @ypercubeᵀᴹ suggested, as another ISNULL

```
WHERE ISNULL(SupervisorApprovedBy,'X') = 
CASE 
    WHEN @UserRole = 'Analyst' THEN 'X'
    ELSE ISNULL(SupervisorApprovedBy,'X')
END
```

Comment: Consider this before adding function on a search predicate http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/55535/sargable-queries-in-sql-server-with-examples/

Comment: Valid point, without seeing the rest of the query or how the output is used or the expected result set to work with, its hard to say if its entirely appropriate or not. I would usually handle nulls in a CTE and filter on that instead